# How to generate a string variable out of a labeled numeric variable (Stata)?

Tags: string, label, stata

I have a variable `state` that takes integer values from 11 to 99. It is labeled.

How can I create a string variable `stateString` that would have string values without all those numeric values?

`gen stateString = tostring(state)`

doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`tostring` isn't a function; it's a command, and in Stata the two are quite distinct. Nothing but guesswork leads to the syntax you tried.

```
tostring state, gen(stateString)
```

should work. But `tostring` is just a wrapper for the function `string()` and

```
gen  stateString = string(state)
```

should also work to get string variables.

But the string values would be "11", ... "99" and that's the wrong approach. Given the value labels, you are fine with having this variable as numeric.

If you really want a string variable, you need `decode`, not `tostring`.

```
decode state, gen(stateString)
```

EDIT: The syntax `tostring()` would only work if `tostring()` were a function, which is not. The original answer thus explained why the OP's code was wrong, as well as explaining how to do it correctly. I spelled out in this edit how to use `decode`.

EDIT 2021: The function `string()` still works and is documented as before, but the function name `strofreal()` is now given prominence.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install Roger Newson's command `sdecode` (`ssc install sdecode`) and then it is just:

```
sdecode state, gen(stateString)
```

Comment: You do not **need** to do this. As already explained, there are more direct solutions using official code only.